# Error writing IN operator in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Need to write a request "select all customers' records from a City of "Paris", "Berlin", "Mannheim" or "London" and their IDs grater than 10, but less that 20"

This is my request:

```
select * from Customers
where CustomerID>10 and CustomerID<20 in
(select * from Customers where City in
('Paris','Berlin','Mannheim','London');
```

And I can't understand why I get **error 1241**: operand should contain 1 column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the correct way of writing this query:

```
select *
from Customers
where CustomerID > 10 and
      CustomerID < 20 and
      City in ('Paris', 'Berlin', 'Mannheim', 'London');
```

Note that list of matching cities represents static data, and hence you don't need a separate subquery to make use of it in the `where in` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BETWEEN` for checking a range of values. And you don't need to add a sub-query for checking the cities. You can use `AND` operator.

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM `Customers`
WHERE `CustomerID` BETWEEN 11 AND 19
AND `City`IN ('Paris','Berlin','Mannheim','London');
```

Comment: I think you need `BETWEEN 11 AND 19` since it is inclusive on both ends.

Answer (score 1):

You did't mention the Column name for IN Condition. You can rewrite the query like

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE City IN ('Paris','Berlin','Mannheim','London') AND CustomerID BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Also like this.Need parenthesis for between statement

```
SELECT * FROM `Customers`
WHERE `CustomerID` (BETWEEN 11 AND 19)
AND `City` IN('Paris','Berlin','Mannheim','London');
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use two `SELECT *`s. Use this:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerID > 10 AND
      CustomerID < 20 AND
      City IN ('Paris', 'Berlin', 'Mannheim', 'London');
```